# Booting Ubuntu 14 on Samsung laptop. rEFInd does not see the hard drive

Tags: boot, uefi, gpt, refind

Good day.

I am having a really hard time trying to get Ubuntu booting on my Samsung Series 3 laptop. Ubuntu has been installed (and it's the only OS), but didn't boot.

I have been through common hints and finally came to a conclusion that there might by a problem with my firmware which I am unable to resolve.

This is the story so far:

1. **boot-repair** complained about GPT. From reading this forum I concluded that since I want to use UEFI, this option does not apply to me. Here is the log, however:

boot-repair info `http://paste.ubuntu.com/11842457/`

2. Tried to add EFI entry manually. Did not work. The entry vanished after reboot
3. Read Roderick Smith's advice on creating a EFI entry manually using his rEFInd. I made a bootable USB, booted into shell and in the mapping table it displayed only a file system fs0 which is the USB itself. HDD is not present so I can't create an EFI since, frankly, **shimx64.efi** is not there. Really disappointing. How is that supposed to work at all?

I have spent days trying to figure out what to do. I really lack a simple and comprehensible guide on how to get Ubuntu working.

**UPDATES**

The EFI partition should contain a directory `/EFI/ubuntu` with four files: `grub.cfg, grubx64.efi, MokManager.efi` and `shimx64.efi`

How can I check that? I've mounted my EFI partition and `ls`'d it. It was empty.

Following Rod's advice, `dmesg` results are [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11849341/)

I think, I need to say that this laptop had preinstalled Windows 8 and so firmware might have been configured in a specific way. I decided to install Ubuntu after old HHD's death and switching to a new one.

After a fix via `gdisk`, Ubuntu finally appeared in `rEFInd`. I see file systems listed in shell other than the USB disk's one. However, I can't `ls` `fs1` which is the EFI partition even though it was displayed as the shell started. Nor can I find `shimx64.efi` anywhere. Tried to boot Ubuntu from options available in `rEFInd`. There were two options:

1. `vmlinuz-3.16.0-43-generic` which resulted in `unable to mount root fs on unknown block(0,0)`
2. `vmlinuz-3.16.0-43-generic.efi.signed` with the same result

[Screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/jl889wqxf/)

Trying to create a EFI entry `bcfg boot add 4 fs1:\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi "Ubuntu"` failed obviously. `fs1` is my EFI partition.

Another bad thing to notice: list of available partitions after that kernel fail is empty.

If I remove the USB with `rEFInd`, still no boot device is present.

Here is bootinfo: `http://paste.ubuntu.com/11850314/`

**Thanks for the answers. Especially to Rod Smith.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my suspicion about emptiness of the EFI partition was not without reason. Ubuntu has not been installed fully because laptop went down due to overheating.
I reinstalled it and it seems to be booting now.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, and you have to do this from then terminal:

```
      sudo apt-get install linux-amd64_ linux-efi
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get upgrade
      sudo apt-get install -f
      sudo apt-get install aptitude
      sudo aptitude linux-efi
```

and it might work fine this way.

Answer (score 0):

Given your configuration, rEFInd and the EFI shell should be showing you both the ESP and the Linux partition. (This assumes that the rEFInd USB drive is configured with the ext4fs driver, which the rEFInd USB images I distribute are.) Thus, my suspicion is that there's something wrong with your hard disk. Try `sudo sgdisk -v /dev/sda` (changing `/dev/sda` to your hard disk's identifier) in an Ubuntu emergency disk. This will test the partition table for errors. If you see any, report back or read my [GPT fdisk documentation on repairing GPT disks.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html)

If there are no GPT problems, try `dmesg > dmesg.txt` from an emergency disk and post the output to [a pastebin site.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) That output may provide a clue about why your disk is not visible to the firmware.

---

**EDIT:** It looks to me as if rEFInd can't find an initial RAM disk (initrd) to match your kernel. Just to be clear, are you launching those kernels from rEFInd or from an EFI shell? I ask because the two filenames you gave (`vmlinuz-3.16.0-43-generic` and `vmlinuz-3.16.0-43-generic.efi.signed`) are identical except for the `.efi.signed` extension, and rEFInd includes code to keep only `.efi.signed` kernels if both are present, so it's odd that both would show up in the rEFInd menu. (OTOH, if you've mis-typed and the kernels vary in their version numbers, then it's perfectly understandable that there'd be two, one with and one without that extension.)

You could look for an initrd file using a live Ubuntu disk, and check what (if any) `initrd=` option rEFInd is passing to the kernel by hitting F2 or Insert twice when you launch the kernel. This procedure will open a text editor that shows the options the kernel is passed, and also enable you to edit those options.

At this point, though, it might be easier to re-install Ubuntu. Unless I misunderstand, this is a fresh installation, so you've got no valuable user data on the system. With the active 0xEE protective partition now inactive, a fresh installation is likely to correct whatever additional problem you've been having.

Comment: Good day Rod. Thank you for the answer. Have just done this. No problems have been reported. By the way, I have just bought this HDD a few days ago. I know some of them are faulty, but the odds are not that high I guess? Also, Ubuntu seems to be installed since I see all the usual content in ext4.

Comment: EXCEPT a warning saying the following:
0xEE protective partition in the MBR is marked active. This is technically a violation of the GPT specification, and can cause some EIFs to ignore the disk, but it is required to boot from a GPT disk on some BIOS-based computers. You can clear this flag by creating a fresh protective MBR using 'n' option on the experts' menu

Comment: That warning almost certainly identifies the cause of your problem, and provides directions for a solution: Use `gdisk`'s `n` option on its experts' menu. (You can also use older versions of `fdisk` to clear this flag. Ubuntu 14.04 ships with an old enough version that it should work.)

Comment: It didn't work. Nothing has changed. `gdisk -l /dev/sda` outputs the same table as before

Comment: `sgdisk` reports no problems, nor warnings though

Comment: You said earlier that `sgdisk -v` *did* display a warning -- "0xEE protective partition in the MBR is marked active... and can cause some EIFs to ignore the disk..." which of course ***is your problem.*** Note that I'm the author of `gdisk` and `sgdisk`; I wrote that warning text based on reports very much like yours. Please don't ignore it. Also, it's counted as a warning rather than the more-serious error because many EFIs do *not* have problems with an active 0xEE protective partition, and in fact that configuration is required to boot some BIOS-based computers from GPT disks.

Comment: I mean AFTER that "n" trick with gdisk (thanks for that btw), no warnings are reported. Meanwhile, I gave up and try to reinstall Ubuntu. One disturbing thing, which I might have overlooked (because at the first time I went to bed leaving Ubuntu installing) is that the laptop accidentally shot down of overheating. So maybe I have yet another problem: i cannot properly install Ubuntu cos my processor is running at extremal frequency.

Comment: So are you still having problems with rEFInd and the EFI shell recognizing the partitions even after using `n` in the `gdisk` experts' menu? Have you tried re-running `sudo sgdisk -v /dev/sda` to verify that the changes were written to disk? (You do have to write them from `gdisk` with `w`; if you didn't do that, you didn't change anything on the disk.)

Comment: Hi @Rod. Please read my update to the question

Comment: I've edited my answer; see above.